# Django FileField update writes to disk but not to database

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models

I am trying to update a `FileField` to an image of something downloaded from internet. I have the following code

```html
# update profile pic
pic_url = fb_login_data['picture']['data']['url']
pic_url_parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(pic_url)
image_req = urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic_url)
with open(image_req[0], 'rb') as f:
    user.profile_image.save(os.path.basename(pic_url_parsed.path),
                                        File(f))
```

The behavior is pretty strange: the image is saved to disk properly in the MEDIA_ROOT directory where it should be, but in database, the field remains empty. I also tried calling `user.save()` manually.

Do you have any ideas why is that happening and how can I update properly the FileField?

using Django 2.0 and Python 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to make it work. All I had to do is to add a default value for the `FileField` to point to an already existing file. But still I am not sure why this is happening.